# use wget for address which include #

Tags: html, wget

I try to use this command for download html file:

```
wget -r --page-requisites  dowload.html https://www.mysite.com/docs//#!Mydocs;location=page1
```

This give me the next error:

```
-bash: !MyDocs: event not found
```

How can I use wget for address which include #?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Encase the URL in single quotes. This stops the shell from parsing the contents.

```
 wget -r --page-requisites  'dowload.html https://www.mysite.com/docs//#!Mydocs;location=page1'
```